# React re-rendering table in new order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, rendering

I've designed a React component that presents a list of To-Dos for a Pet Store in block format so that users can organize To-Dos in category blocks rather than just a list of unorganized To-Dos. You can add a block at the beginning, anywhere in the middle or the end of the list of blocks and this works properly in the backend, however, when testing the add functionality, instead of adding blocks wherever you've chosen, my table consistently adds them to the bottom of the table **even though** in the component state the order is correct.

Here's the component code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext, Fragment } from 'react';
import ManagerContext from '../../../context/manager/managerContext';
import M from 'materialize-css';
import Todo from './Todo';

const Open = () => {
  const managerContext = useContext(ManagerContext);
  const {
    openBlocks,
    openTodos,
    addNewBlock,
  } = managerContext;

  useEffect(() => {
    M.AutoInit();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [openBlocks]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Opening Tasks</h2>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {openBlocks !== null &&
            openBlocks.map((block) => (
              <Fragment key={block.blockNum}>
                <tr>
                  <td className="filler">
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                      onClick={() => {
                        addNewBlock('Open', block.blockNum, openBlocks);
                      }}
                    >
                      {block.blockNum === 1
                        ? `Add new block above Block #${block.blockNum}`
                        : `Add new block between Block #${
                            block.blockNum - 1
                          } & Block #${block.blockNum}`}
                    </button>
                  </td>
                  <td className="filler" colSpan="2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td className="block-filler text-center">
                    <b>Block #{block.blockNum}</b>
                  </td>
                  <td className="block-filler text-center" colSpan="2">
                    <button className="btn btn-danger">Remove Block</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Description</th>
                  <th>Category</th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
                {openBlocks.map((b) =>
                    b.todos.map(
                      (todo) =>
                        todo.block === block.blockNum && (
                          <Todo key={todo.id} todo={todo} />
                        )
                    )
                  )}
                <tr>
                  <td className="filler">
                    <select name="addToBlock" id="addToBlock" defaultValue="">
                      <option value="" disabled>
                        Assign To-Do to Block #{block.blockNum}
                      </option>
                      {openTodos !== null &&
                        openTodos.map(
                          (t) =>
                            t.block === 0 && (
                              <option key={t.id} value={t.id}>
                                {t.todo} ({t.category} Task)
                              </option>
                            )
                        )}
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td className="filler" colSpan="2"></td>
                </tr>
                {block.blockNum === openBlocks.length && (
                  <tr>
                    <td className="filler">
                      <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                        Add new block below Block #{block.blockNum}
                      </button>
                    </td>
                    <td className="filler" colSpan="2"></td>
                  </tr>
                )}
              </Fragment>
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Open;
```

Here's the state of `openBlocks` upon loading the data from the backend:

```
[
   {blockNum: 1, todos: Array(1)}
   {blockNum: 2, todos: Array(4)}
   {blockNum: 3, todos: Array(2)}
   {blockNum: 4, todos: Array(1)}
   {blockNum: 5, todos: Array(2)}
   {blockNum: 6, todos: Array(6)}
   {blockNum: 7, todos: Array(1)}
]
```

Here's the component in the browser:

[image: Block list in numerical order]

As you can see, it loads the content of `openBlocks` into sequentially numbered blocks.

When using the **"Add new block above Block #1"** button, it shows up in the state at the beginning properly:

```
[
   {blockNum: 1, todos: Array(0)}
   {blockNum: 2, todos: Array(1)}
   {blockNum: 3, todos: Array(4)}
   {blockNum: 4, todos: Array(2)}
   {blockNum: 5, todos: Array(1)}
   {blockNum: 6, todos: Array(2)}
   {blockNum: 7, todos: Array(6)}
   {blockNum: 8, todos: Array(1)}
]
```

However, the component instead loads the new block at the **end**.

[image: Block #8 placed at the end of the block table list instead of at the beginning]

I feel like the issue lies in how html tables are rendered and therefore trying to add new data into an established table requires manipulating the DOM. I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well i made a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-lovelace-1u7j2) and it works just fine. The problem was logic related and you just need to find the index by `blockNum` before inserting.

Comment: but that doesn't explain how the backend state is properly adding the new Array value based on blockNum and then displaying it differently. For example, as I provided above, Block #8 is showing on the back-end to show Block #7's contents prior to adding the new Block #1, however on the front-end Block #8 is blank.

Comment: I have now attempted to sort the array using .map().sort() and after that didn't work I tried using the useState hook where I took the openBlocks, sorted using .sort() then took the result and placed it into a useState object and STILL the back-end is correct with the front-end just plopping new blocks at the end for no apparent reason.